# No devenv file in Microsoft visual Express 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devenv

i am trying to build the google dart project on windows XP.

following the installation documentation, i ran accross a problem. The python script needs to call devenv. The problem is that with Visual 10 Express, i don't have this exe which should be in

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE
```

Where can i get this exe ? Do i need to download a prior version that visual 10 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9778593/441092) that needed me to edit `devenv.exe.config` which doesn't exist in VCExpress and learned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805545/441092) that the name of the exe (and of course it's matching `.config` file) depends on the version of Visual Studio.

In the "complete" versions of VS such as VSPro the executable you're looking for is indeed `devenv.exe` but in Express it's `vcexpress.exe` (or the equivalent for your Express version eg vbexpress.exe for Visual Basic Express etc) so it's not so much that Express doesn't include `devenv.exe` but that it's called something else and presumably not all command line options under `devenv.exe` will be available or perform the same as `v*express.exe`.

Comment: In VS2013 for windows Desktop it is WDExpress.exe

Comment: @MiguelGamboa, you mean: ***VS2013 Express*** For Windows Desktop.

Comment: *VS2013 Express For Windows* is VSWinExpress.exe, and *VS2013 Express for Web* is VWDExpress.exe

Comment: Also, note the file path will **likely** be: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE* for these VS2013 Express executables (the **devenv.exe** equivalent)

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried MSBuild? MSDN now recommands [using MSBuild instead of devenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx). MSBuild  seems to come along with VC Express at no cost.

To build a solution with configuration Debug|Win32 using MSBuild:

```
msbuild xxx.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=Win32
```

More detailed [MSBuild usage is available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

devenv.exe is the Visual Studio Shell executable. Just follow your Start Menu link to your Express edition. It should point to your devenv.exe.

Comment: Hm, the thing is that the menu item "Visual Command Prompt" points to "%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 " and not an exe ,

Comment: open the batch vcvarsall.bat file and look for the executable.

Comment: well i did that, it points me to another series of batch file (like this : if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat") and in these files i don't see any devenv.exe mentionned.

Comment: Have you tried to search that file with windows? Or did a "dir /s devenx.exe" on the command line?

Comment: Yup, no result... As i go deeper searching the internet, it seems that devenv is only part of the non express Visual..

Comment: Thanks for searching the internet afterwards. :(

Answer (score 0):

Scripts depending on devenv are likely to work if you create a devenv.bat with content

```
%dp0%vcsexpress.exe %*
```