# VS2010 Express missing devenv.exe so I can't fix "project out of date" issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm actually trying to fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2762930/441092) issue where my projects are always out of date by using the steps outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754740/441092) to enable system logging.

However I can't find `devenv.exe.config` or the matching .exe file anywhere on my machine let alone in either `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

I'm running Windows 7 SP1 (which I presume isn't particularly relevant) and VS2010 Express SP1. I was thinking that maybe devenv isn't available in the Express version but I can't find any info to either confirm or deny my theory.

Can anyone suggest why I don't have devenv.exe and whether I should or not?

If not, how do I fix the "always out of date" issue without being able to get a proper log that tells me what's causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have `vcexpress.exe.config`?

Comment: Yes I do and it has the appropriate `<configsections>` section after which the `<system.diagnostics>` section is added but I can't save the file. It seems to be file locked by some other program (even immediately after a reboot). There's nothing showing in Task Manager that is immediately obvious to me as the culprit.

Comment: In an effort to solve the lock problem first, I've tried using SysInternals `Handle` but it reports "no matching handles found". `Unlocker` also says "no locking handle". Given that this is outside the scope of the original question, I'll try to resolve this elsewhere first so I can then check if editing `vcexpress.exe.config` does what I'm after (thanks to @EdwardThomson for the suggestion).

Comment: @Edward: File lock issue solved, editing `vcexpress.exe.config` does indeed do the job. I had assumed (incorrectly I'm guessing) that VS Pro would have a `VC.exe` and `devenv.exe` was something different.  If you care to add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer and upvote (if I can, still getting used to SO).

Comment: You bet.  Out of curiosity, what was locking the file?

Comment: Actually it wasn't a lock as such, just admin privileges. Although I'm an administrator (in fact the only user on my laptop), apparently when I go to edit the file it doesn't open with admin rights. I had to give Users write permission to be able to save changes.

Comment: And I can't upvote - not enough rep yet, sorry. I'll come back and do so when I do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the executable (and, of course, the associated configuration file) is dependent upon which type of Visual Studio you're running.  Normally, this is `devenv.exe`.  In the case of Visual Studio Express, you should be able to locate `vcexpress.exe`.

A similar configuration file is available as `vcexpress.exe.config`, and you should be able to place your `system.diagnostics` configuration in that file.

Comment: In my case, it's WDExpress. But this answer is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

you can find your path by

- right click on icon and select property window
- in shortcut tab you can find out in target textbox

In my VS 2012 Express it looking as :

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe"

Answer (score 0):

In my case of "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express Version4 for Windows Phone" it's the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VPDExpress.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Just start a new process from task manager as shows below

File>Run New task>devenv.exe

Answer (score -1):

In the case of "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone" it´s the VPDExpress.exe (.config)
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

Comment: Where would this file be located?

Comment: This worked for me (the devenv.exe file was in the IDE directory).