# Is the visual c++ express cmd prompt missing features?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, poco-libraries

I tried compiling the POCO library on my Windows 7 computer. Though I use eclipse cdt, it said that It could only be compiled with Visual C++:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 7.1 (2003), 8.0 (2005), 9.0 (2008) or 10.0
>   (2010) is required to build the POCO C++ Libraries on Windows
>   platforms. Solution and project files for all versions are included.
>   For Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, 64-bit (x64) builds are supported as
>   well. You can either build from within Visual Studio (Build->Batch
>   Build->Select All;Rebuild) or from the command line. To build from the
>   command line, start the Visual Studio .NET 2003/2005/2008/2010 Command
>   Prompt and go (cd) to the directory where you have extracted the POCO
>   C++ Libraries sources. Then, simply start the buildwin.cmd script and
>   pass as argument the version of visual studio (71, 80, 90 or 100). You
>   can customize what is being built by buildwin.cmd by passing
>   appropriate command line arguments to it. Call buildwin.cmd without
>   arguments to see what is available. To disable certain components
>   (e.g., NetSSL_OpenSSL or Data/MySQL) from the build, edit the text
>   file named components in the distribution root directory and remove
>   the respective lines. Certain libraries, like NetSSL_OpenSSL, Crypto
>   or Data/MySQL have dependencies to other libraries. Since the build
>   script does not know where to find the necessary header files and
>   import libraries, you have to either add the header file paths to the
>   INCLUDE environment variable and the library path to the LIB
>   environment variable, or you'll have to edit the buildwin.cmd script,
>   where these environment variables can be set as well. In order to run
>   the test suite and the samples, the top-most bin directory containing
>   the resulting shared libraries must be in the PATH environment
>   variable.

I downloaded visual c++ express, but when I run the "buildwin.cmd" I get these errors:

```
devenv is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

I also can't find any "build" menue inside the program. Is the full Visual C++ required to build the library? If so, is there any cheaper option?

Comment: devenv is not part of the Express editions of Visual Studio as far as I know. I think you might either want to look at the msbuild or vcexpress command line options.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818543/no-devenv-file-in-microsoft-visual-express-10