# Upgrade a visual studio solution on the command line with visual studio express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Is there a way to upgrade a visual studio solution on the command line with visual studio express?

When trying to build the old solution with msbuild I get a warning to upgrade with either "vcbuild /upgrade" or "devenv /upgrade". Both of them do not exist in VS Express 2012 and msbuild from that version does not include an /upgrade flag. I also found a solution proposing to use vcupgrade, which exists but can only upgrade individual projects. Also, the upgrade fails in my case, whereas it is completely possible using the GUI.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818543/no-devenv-file-in-microsoft-visual-express-10

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot find a an executable called vcexpress.exe in 2012. One comment there suggests that wdexpress.exe shall be used, but this on does not have any upgrade flag.

Comment: vcexpress is "C# Express" I believe.      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express

Comment: I just searched the whole install tree of visual studio express again. There is no exe file that ends on express apart from wdexpress.exe, which does not provide update functionality via the command line.

Comment: Yeah.  I think you're screw-balled.  I don't see any commandline args for any of the *express.exe's.