# What determines the default startup project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a open source project that include Visual Studio project files. There is a solution file with four projects files. When the source files are distributed and unpacked, Visual Studio picks the wrong project as the default project. New users don't know they need to right click a certain project, and then select ***Set as Startup Project***.

I've tried re-ordering the projects in the solution file so the appropriate project is first, and I tried changing the UUID on the appropriate project so its the lowest. Neither have helped with the problem of Visual Studio selecting the wrong startup project.

The Visual Studio versions I test against are Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 and [<strike>2015</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32438478).

What determines the default startup project?

What can I do to ensure Visual Studio selects the correct startup project?

---

A related question is [Why is “Set as Startup” option stored in the suo file and not the sln file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/694730), but it asks "Why..." and does not ask "How To...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If there is a *.suo file, the Startup Project is saved there.
2. Otherwise, the first project listed in the *.sln file will be the Startup.

(tested with VS 2013)

Comment: Thanks Vlad... I finally got back to Windows testing. Sorry about the delay in accepting.