# Visual Studio build project with required project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, visual-studio-2013

I am refactored library, and now it few module projects and one main. Main references all modules, and modules references each other(as they need). And finaly, main project is empty, and 'Link Library Dependencies' flag is enabled.
(VS2013/VS2012, all projects .lib)

In library solution build success, and resulting library linked success, and all external projects that require this lib work fine.

But i want that library be part of many solutions(as git submodule), and here i get problem. In past, i just add MyLibrary.vcxproj to SomeProject.sln, end get awersome results. Now i get bundle of linking error (.lib is missing). Its happens because project reference require only resulting .lib file, and nowhere said "build some project to get that lib".

So here the complete question:
If i have some project, that require some other projects to be build before, and i want use that project results in many solutions, what i should do, to get project dependencies without add `some other projects` to that solution. Perfect result: if i dont need to change solution properties.
Custom build steps accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i solved it. Here the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx).

You should add in that Main project file custom build step `devenv FullPathToSolution/Main.sln /build`

Note, that in express version [devenv is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818543/no-devenv-file-in-microsoft-visual-express-10). So my custom build look like this:

`"$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86)\..\..\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe" "$(ProjectDir)/../AX.sln" /build`